# Remove elements contains lowercase & null from list

Tags: python, list, random, character

I have a list that contains words, numbers & some random characters.I want to remove elements that contain other than UPPERCASE, Punctuation & Digits.

```
list_of_words =  ['S I NGHVI', '', 'MGANPAT', '/', '', '', 'q', 'gq6', '14', 'A -_']
for i in list_of_words:
    for j in i:
        if ord(j) not in range(65,91): # for shortlisting A-Z ascii values
            del list_of_words[i]
```

is throwing me error like this:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Output I want:

```
list_of_words = ['S I NGHVI', 'MGANPAT', '/', '14', 'A -_']
```

Comment: You want the `'/'` and the `'A -_'` too? Meaning you want all punctuation?

Comment: @A.J.Uppal Not really. But I want to read CAP letters than it would be problematic right. I would require `'/'` for sure.Want to remove elements that contains non-CAP letters.

Comment: Not at all :) You can simply filter through each word using something like `all([letter in string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits for letter in word])` after looping through each word in the list.

Comment: `list_word` is not defined, you are using a string as an index (?), `is not in` should be `not in`, and after that, it still doesn't work

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 I have mistakenly wrote `list_word` instead `list_of_words`. Thank you for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```
from string import *
list_of_words = [word for word in list_of_words if all([letter in punctuation+ascii_uppercase+digits+' ' for letter in word]) and word]
```

---

```
>>> from string import *                                                        
>>> list_of_words =  ['S I NGHVI', '', 'MGANPAT', '/', '', '', 'q', 'gq6', '14', 'A -_']
>>> list_of_words = [word for word in list_of_words if all([letter in punctuation+ascii_uppercase+digits+' ' for letter in word])]
>>> list_of_words
['S I NGHVI', 'MGANPAT', '/', '14', 'A -_']
>>>
```

---

You have a couple issues in your code:

1. Do not use `del` to remove from a list, you can use `.remove()`, `.pop()`, or simply overwrite the list.
2. `list_word` is not defined, perhaps you meant `list_of_words`?
3. Using `ord` is not as readable and concise as using the `string` module. Simply `import string` and call `dir(string)` to see the various predefined character sets you can access.
4. You are using `is` wrong; `is` compares the `id`s of two objects. In this case, you can simply omit it and use `not in`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it gives me output: `['S I NGHVI', '', 'MGANPAT', '/', '', '', '14', 'A -_']`. How to remove null?

Comment: @abhi1610 it works just fine for me, try copying the code again

Comment: I like this approach: this is what I would use to get the sample output as shown in the question (as opposed to following the word description that I matched).  To remove the empty strings, though, I would use: `[word for word in list_of_words if word and all([letter in punctuation+ascii_uppercase+digits+' ' for letter in word])]`

Comment: @John1024I have rephrased my questions. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal Thank you for the answer and suggestion.

Comment: `list(filter(None, [word for word in list_of_words if all([letter in punctuation+ascii_uppercase+digits+' ' for letter in word])]))` would work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer for first version of question

To get *"only CAPITAL letter words & numbers"*:

```
>>> [w for w in list_of_words if w.isupper() or w.isdigit()]
['S I NGHVI', 'MGANPAT', '14', 'A -_']
```

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 This produces what he says he wants.  It is true that the sample output provided and the description provided don't match.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 John is right, the OP was unclear, both John and I took different approaches, I took his question as intended by his sample output, John took his actual question.